# Is there a code to make NextJs routing cube transition effect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-animations, next.js

I am trying to route page as a cube. Is there any way to make it with using NextJs and [next-page-transitions](https://github.com/illinois/next-page-transitions)?

My _app.js looking like this on the begin.

```
<Layout>
  <PageTransition timeout={300} classNames="page-transition">
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </PageTransition>
</Layout>
```